# How to calculate cumulative sum for the interval defined by a different column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate cumulative sum of numbers in one column with the length of the vector to be summed being variable and defined by values in another column.

An example:

```
ti <- tibble(group = c(rep("A", 18), rep("B", 18)),
             year = c(1990:2007,1991:2008),
             x = c(NA, NA, NA, 20, NA, NA, NA, 15, NA, NA, NA, 3, 5, NA, 9, NA, NA, 20,
                   20, NA, 17, NA, NA, NA, 30, 10, NA, NA, NA, 8, 17, NA, NA, NA, NA, 30),
             y = c(sample(1:100, 18), sample(1:100, 18)))
```

[image]

I would like to get the cumulative sum of y in rows where x is non-NA, i.e.

[image]

etc.

Ideally, the solution should work with %>% and group_by.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution should work.

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(220)

ti <- tibble(group = c(rep("A", 18), rep("B", 18)),
             year = c(1990:2007,1991:2008),
             x = c(NA, NA, NA, 20, NA, NA, NA, 15, NA, NA, NA, 3, 5, NA, 9, NA, NA, 20,
                   20, NA, 17, NA, NA, NA, 30, 10, NA, NA, NA, 8, 17, NA, NA, NA, NA, 30),
             y = c(sample(1:100, 18), sample(1:100, 18)))

ti %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(y =  cumsum(y)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(x))

#> # A tibble: 13 x 4
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>    group  year     x     y
#>    <chr> <int> <dbl> <int>
#>  1     A  1993    20   203
#>  2     A  1997    15   458
#>  3     A  2001     3   621
#>  4     A  2002     5   636
#>  5     A  2004     9   761
#>  6     A  2007    20   906
#>  7     B  1991    20    15
#>  8     B  1993    17   104
#>  9     B  1997    30   409
#> 10     B  1998    10   457
#> 11     B  2002     8   595
#> 12     B  2003    17   694
#> 13     B  2008    30   888
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the solution! That was embarrassingly simple :)